# Netbeans не может перейти к объявлению функции as_array в PHP. Почему так?

Tags: php, netbeans

Вот код.
Зажимаю Ctrl и щелкаю мышкой на as_array. Слышу звук ошибки и ничего не происходит (меня не перекидывает к объявлению функции). Почему так?

```
    $catalog_ids = array();
    if ( ! is_object($catalog) )
    {
        $catalog_id = 0;
        foreach(ORM::factory('Catalog')->where('catalog_id', '=', 0)->find_all() as $v)
        {
            if ($v->id == $material_id) {
              $catalog_ids = array_merge($v->get_childs()->as_array(NULL, 'id'), $catalog_ids);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $catalog_id = $catalog->id;
        $catalog_ids = $catalog->get_childs()->as_array(NULL, 'id');
    }
```

Comment: Так это разве функция php? :)

Comment: Весь код на php.